# How to declare dependency on Play's Anorm for a standalone application?

Tags: scala, sbt, anorm

What is the current sbt syntax for using a recent version (say, 2.3 or 2.4) of Play's **anorm** package in standalone mode (not part of a Play application)?

Comment: @applicius nailed it, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anorm is now published as follows with no need for an additional resolver.

```
"org.playframework.anorm" %% "anorm" % "2.6.2"
```

Answer (score 11):

In `build.sbt`:

```scala
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.6")
```

See [example](https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte/blob/10m-anorm-tutorial/build.sbt).

Comment: Yes, i think that was one of the examples i found via Google. It doesn't work: 

`[warn] Host repo.typeseafe.com not found. url=http://repo.typeseafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/anorm_2.11/2.3.2/anorm_2.11-2.3.2.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.`

`sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#anorm_2.11;2.3.2: not found`

Comment: It does work, so your issue is elsewhere. https://travis-ci.org/cchantep/acolyte/builds/31466513 . Check your network config and/or possible HTTP proxy.

Comment: I created a `build.sbt` containing only this dependency, and pasted the results above, in my question.

Comment: Maybe you should write `repo.typesafe.com` (as in answer), instead of `repo.typeseafe.com`.